# Converting a math string into a JavaScript expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to convert a string into a valid JavaScript expression using JavaScript.

For example:

- `4x+2y+1z` should be converted to `4*x+2*y+1*z`
- `12r+6s` should be converted to `12*r+6*s`

I have tried to do this using a regular expression, but I was not able to do so successfully.

Comment: There is a reason you haven't been able to do this successfully: this cannot be done using regular expressions alone.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy can you suggest me some method

Comment: So to be clear, you're converting a typical math string to a string that is valid JavaScript?

Comment: This works for your current input. `'4x+2y+1z'.replace(/(\d)([a-z])/g, '$1*$2')`

Comment: yes, that what I have to do

Comment: @AvinashRaj You might want to do `\d+` and account for whitespace characters

Comment: @thefourtheye i think no.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Try `12r+6s`, from the question.

Comment: yes, it returns `12*r+6*s` . What's wrong with this?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Ah, you are right... Don't have to capture the entire number.

Comment: So do you need to worry about brackets like `2(3x)` or not?

Answer (score 3):

```
(\d+)(?=[a-z])
```

Try this.Replace by `$1*`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/rQ6mK9/31

Comment: Why you use lookahead here?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I dont want two groups and use `$2`

Comment: go for a lookahead only if it's not possible through captures. Check the performance of  two regexes in the demo site. @Qantas94Heavy

Answer (score 1):

The below code would work for your current input.

```
> '4x+2y+1z'.replace(/(\d)([a-z])/g, '$1*$2')
'4*x+2*y+1*z'
> '12r+6s'.replace(/(\d)([a-z])/g, '$1*$2')
'12*r+6*s'
```

Comment: There's actually no need for `$2`.Seems overkill

Comment: @vks: it's not overkill, it performs the same function. Personally, I prefer terseness over performance unless necessary, but it's a personal call for such a small piece of code.

Comment: that's not the point here.See the steps in debugger.Yours takes 500+ steps.Lookaehad takes 12 steps.That should clear your doubts  @Qantas94Heavy

Comment: @AvinashRaj dont know what you looking at.Here are the 2 regexs.  http://regex101.com/r/rQ6mK9/33 http://regex101.com/r/rQ6mK9/34 try and see d debugger

Comment: @AvinashRaj whatever be the input...yours checks each digit and sees if theres is a chars ahead.so that will take much more steps.change your regex to `\d+` to make it better

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**

Try following code:

```
function strToExpression(str)
{
    return str.replace(/(\d)+([A-Za-z])/g, '$1*$2');
}

var firstExpression = strToExpression('4x+2y+1z');
var secondExpression = strToExpression('12r+6s');
```